# Mysql Select values from two files print only values not exist in first table

Tags: mysql, select

I have two tables ini mysql database

First

```
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
9.10.11.12
13.14.15.16
17.18.19.20
21.22.23.24
```

Second

```
a.b.c.d
e.f.g.h
1.2.3.4
13.14.15.16
21.22.23.24
25.26.27.28
29.30.31.32
33.34.35.36
```

I want to select values from the two tables and print Only values that not exist in the first table ignoring value that not exist in the second table.

The result should be :

```
5.6.7.8
9.10.11.12
17.18.19.20
```

I think I've search all the result in stackoverflow. And I know some basic mysql . But nothing gave me the result I expected. Hard to explain I know. Or maybe I made simple think complicated I don't know :D.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use sql distint statement.....

eg : SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Customers

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, as it's been answered many times ,as I suspected I've made a simple thing complicated with to much data. :D.